# CSS How do I ask for both max-height and max-width?

Tags: css

I know how to ask for `max-width` or `max-height` in CSS. I usually do it like this:

`@media screen and (max-width: 1920) {}`

or for `height`,

`@media screen and (max-height: 1080) {}`

but how would I write it if I wanted to ask if it was both `max-height` and `max-width` **in the same rule**?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) `@media screen and (max-width: 1920) and (max-height: 1080) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correclty, what you want to do is ask for both max-height and max-width in the same query string sentence. If that is the case you just need to create this css block:

```
@media screen and (min-height: 720px) and (min-width: 1920px) {
   /* CSS rules here*/
}
```

Let me know if that is what you needed.

If you want to ask for one OR the other just just replace `and` for a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "and" to combine parenthetical condition statements.

`@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (max-height: 1000px) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `&&` selector

```
(max-width: 1920) && (max-height: 1000px) {}
```